# ODBC Equivalent of DBMS_ALERT in Oracle

Tags: c++, visual-studio, odbc, alert

Is there anything (system procedure,function or other) in SQL Server that will provide the functionality of DBMS_ALERT package of ORACLE (and DBMS_PIPE respectively)?

I work in a plant and I'm using an extension-product of SQL-Server called InSQL Server by Wonderware which is specialized in gothering data from plant controllers and HumanMachineInterface(SCADA) software.

This system can record events happening in the plant (like a high-temperature alarm, for example). It stores sensor values in extension tables  of SQL Sever, and other less dense information in normal SQL Server tables.

I want to be able to alert some applications running on operator PCs that an event has been recorded in the database.

An after insert trigger in the events table seems to be a good place to put something equivalent to DBMS_ALERT (if it exists), to wake up other applications that are waiting for the specific alert and have the operators type in some data.

In other words - I want to be able to notify other processes (that have connection to SQL Server) that something has happened in the database.

Answer (score 0):

All Wonderware (InSQL but now called Aveva) Historian data is stored in the history blocks EXCEPT for the actual tag storage configuration and dedicated event data.  The time series data for analog, discrete and strings is NOT in SQL tables at all - unless someone is doing custom configuration to. create tables of their own.

Where are you wanting these notifications to come up?  Even though the historical data is NOT stored in SQL tables, Wonderware has extensive documentation on how to use SQL queries to appropriately retrieve data (check for whatever condition you are looking for)

You can easily build a stored procedure and configure it for a maintenance plan.

But are you just trying to alarm (provide notification) on the scada itself?
Or are you truly utilizing historical data (looking for a data trend - average, etc.)?
Or trying to send the notification to non-scada interfaces?

Depending on your specific answer, the scada itself should probably be able to do it.

But there is software that already does this type of thing Win-911, SeQent, Scadatec are a couple in the OT space.  But also things like Hip Link or even DeskAlert which can connect to any SQL via it's own API.

So where does the info need to go (email, text, phone, desktop app...) and what is the real source of the data>